# Using Pandas, i'm trying to keep on my DataFrame only 100 rows of each value of my column "neighborhood"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a super large dataset that i'm trying to shrink.
My idea is to keep 100 rows by neighborhood.

Here's an overview of my data :

| index | name | neighborhood |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name 1 | neighborhood A |
| 1 | name 2 | neighborhood A |
| 2 | name 3 | neighborhood B |
| 3 | name 4 | neighborhood B |
| 4 | name 5 | neighborhood C |
| 5 | name 6 | neighborhood C |
| 6 | name 7 | neighborhood D |
| 7 | name 8 | neighborhood D |
| 8 | name 9 | neighborhood E |
| 9 | name 10 | neighborhood E |

What is the more efficient way to do so ?

Thanks in advance

I'm expecting to create something that looks like :

| index | name | neighborhood |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name 1 | neighborhood A |
| 1 | name 3 | neighborhood B |
| 2 | name 5 | neighborhood C |
| 3 | name 7 | neighborhood D |
| 4 | name 9 | neighborhood E |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, you can use **groupby** and **nth*:

```
dfx=df.groupby('neighborhood').nth[:100]
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends **how** you want to select the rows.

##### first n with [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
n = 100
out = df.groupby('neighborhood').head(n)
```

##### random n rows with [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
n = 100
out = df.groupby('neighborhood').sample(n=n)
```